# How to get CSRF token with rails3.2.x, before sending restful POST/PUT API, without any form/UI from server side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, csrf

I know rails provided CSRF protection by default from rails3.
but my web application is a single page application, and all communication depend on ajax.

So, how can I get CSRF token from server before each ajax calling?
or what I can do is just take off CSRF protection, right?

NOTE: we don't use any rails view to produce the web page, even the homepage, so the solution to **put "<%= csrf_meta_tag %> " in .html or .erb is invalid**., we use javascript framework within one page.

my env: rails3.2.3, devise2.0.4, dojo1.7.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advice you to take a look at the [Rails-backbone](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails) project. Specifically the [backbone_rails_sync.js](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/backbone_rails_sync.js#L21-L31) file.

It shows how this gem sends the CSRF-token data along with any ajax request you make to the server.

Also, here are some [docs by the Django project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) that give you an example of how to override the default jQuery ajax() method to always send a CSRF token.

**updated based on comment:**

So what you where asking is how to implement CSRF when using nothing but a REST API and no views/forms are used in any way.

The answer is: **don't include CSRF protection**.

[Cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF) is a way where another (malicious) web site reproduces or imitates a request and poses as a valid user while sending invalid data to the server.

This is only a problem when a user needs to authenticate and the authentication state is saved in the cache (to persist between page views). If a malicious web site hijacks this cache, it can submit data while pretending to be this user, without the user and server ever noticing this. This is what CSRF protection is hired to do, it injects a special string into the form that is only valid for this particular request and is unique for each other request, so even if the session is hijacked, the CSRF protection prevents any modification on the server.

In your case however, you are using HTTP API calls, and thus have to send your authentication every request through the use of the `Authorization header`. This way, the credentials are never cached and can't be hijacked, so there is no need for CSRF protection.

There are other ways however to make sure your RESTful API is secure:

- **Always send data over the wire in an encrypted form (https/ssl)**
- Use a good authentication method like oAuth(2), API tokens or Basic HTTP Authentication *(the last two are less secure, but still secure enough for smaller applications)*
- Always check every value going into your application before acting on them

Comment: thanks for your information. But maybe some misunderstanding.

Comment: thanks for your information. But maybe some misunderstanding.  Actually, I want to know how to get the csrf token, if I just send a ajax request?  <br/>I read some posts, which say put "<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
" in the layout of .html or .erb. But my client only uses restful API, so no form/UI from server side before sending ajax request, so the solution above is invalid. Can I send a special ajax request to server to get the CSRF token first, then send ajax request with this CSRF?   Or some other solutions?

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment. The short of it: you don't need CSRF protection in your case.

Comment: Much closer.  session is used in this application, and the authentication happens when user login(we don't authenticate for each request). So, I think CSRF risk is here. But due to the architect/design, this is Rich Internet Application(single page application), so, all UI components are produced on client side, have nothing to do with server. So, we cannot get CSRF token from server. But I want CSRF protection, and I think this application has CSRF risk. But I don't know whether it is possibile to get CSRF protect in this kind of application. If yes, how?

Comment: Well, since `csrf_meta_tag` is just a method available in your views (and possibly controllers as well), why don't you then provide an API end-point to access this token? Something like /token/csrf which responds to JSON with something like {csrf: TOKEN_HERE}. But, as I've said before, the csrf token only works for a single session, so I don't know if this would actually work (and I am inclined to say that it won't).

Comment: Also, as a final note, if you say the user needs to log in, that means you DO communicate with the server initially (I presume the login screen is a view in your Rails app?), then why can't you send the csrf token when the user logs in? If that doesn't work, and my above solution doesn't work, and you tested that you are actually vulnerable to the CSRF attack, then there is only one good solution: redesign your app. It isn't worth risking security over this.